# How to INSERT INTO table WHERE one of the values taken from selection

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I have three tables:

— *usergroup*
— *user* which contains among others the usergroupid external key
— *subscribeforum* with subscribeforumid (auto incr), userid, forumid, emailupdate

and I need to insert into *subscribeforum* all users that belong to usergroups 2 and 12 (the rest of the values: forumid 2 and emailupdate 2)

The following doesn't work, of course, as it "returns more than one record"

```
INSERT INTO subscribeforum ()
VALUES ((SELECT userid 
         FROM user
         WHERE (usergroupid = 2) OR (usergroupid = 12)), 2, 2)
```

I had thought something in the following logic:

```
INSERT INTO subscribeforum (userid, forumid, emailupdate)
VALUES (uid, 2, 2)
WHERE uid IN
(SELECT userid FROM user WHERE (usergroupid = 2) OR (usergroupid = 12))
```

But, I don't know the right way to complete it.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO subscribeforum (userid, forumid, emailupdate)
SELECT userid ,2, 2 FROM user WHERE (usergroupid = 2) OR (usergroupid = 12)
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: I had just figured it out myself, searching the web. It so simple as the INSERT INTO SELECT syntax prevails. Thanks Danilo!

Comment: (btw the right forumid is 12)
Anyway, when I try to execute this:
INSERT INTO subscribeforum (userid, forumid, emailupdate)
SELECT userid, 21, 2
FROM user
WHERE (usergroupid = 2) OR (usergroupid = 12)

I get: "An error occurred while attempting to execute your query. The following information was returned.
error number: 1062
error desc: Duplicate entry '2-21' for key 'subindex'"

Comment: the table does not accept for User 2 the same forumid, You can solve it by adding a group by userid

Comment: Yes, I understand now what's wrong. User 2 already exists in the subscribeforum table with forumid 21. 

Do you think this would work?

INSERT INTO subscribeforum (userid, forumid, emailupdate)
SELECT userid, 21, 2
FROM user
WHERE (usergroupid = 2) OR (usergroupid = 12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  emailupdate = 2;

in case of duplicate key, just update the not so important emailupdate field?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly, though. I can tell from the number of Affected Rows which is way more than it should be. :/ We use SELECT with two constants there (21 and 2). Is that a correct use?

Comment: I executed four such queires (for different forumids). Eventhough the first one returned kind of too many affected rows, the other three worked as expected. So, I think, that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, let me know if you have any other questions